Is there an ethical view that we should always do what is most naturally human?
I vaguely remember reading something about this, and I want to research it further but I have no idea where to look. What I'm looking for is a theory among these lines:
Almost all problems we face as humans were created by ourselves as a species. A big example of this is cancer - we eat processed foods, breathe dirty air, and are subject to all sorts of other man-made carcinogens; and today 1 in 2 people will develop cancer in their lives. These carcinogens are caused by us as a species doing things that are beyond the natural order of how Earth was set up to function as an ecosystem, and how our bodies are evolved to function.
Edit: I've been made aware by the comments that cancer was not a great example to use. Instead, consider any other problem caused by us as a species doing things that are beyond the natural order of how Earth was set up to function as an ecosystem - chemicals and toxins in our food or in the atmosphere give us all sorts of health problems.
As for the distinguishing between the natural from the unnatural, all I mean as natural are the activities and behaviours humans are adapted to doing. For example, we are adapted to walk barefoot - I was curious to know if there was an ethical theory that would argue this means we ought to walk barefoot. (I realise now my question was badly phrased... but this was what I meant)
Edit: I was looking for state of nature philosophy. Thanks for the help.

Yes, cancer is not a great example, environmental factors only increase our natural potential to get cancer, but we have a natural base probability no matter how healthy or morally we live.

The question should give more hints, maybe as related to the naturalistic fallacy, the Amish, or the switch from hunter-gatherer to sedentary lifestyle. All of which could be related.

I could be wrong, but I don't think you will much serious philosophy along those lines because of the obvious problem that there's no real way to distinguish the natural from the unnatural. However, there have been literary figures that said things along those lines, such as Thoreau and the Romantic authors who talked about the Noble Savage.

The way the earth was set up most of us should die by the age of 40. An awful lot of cancer is due to many of us living longer than we should "naturally". But you can definitely find a lot of rip-off artists who will help you descend into a paranoid version of these beliefs.

No, according to my understanding of Schopenhauer's philosophy, the world's blind will controls that suffering is part of its realities, and he suggests that we tolerate this suffering and consider it part of the realities of the world and not fight it.

Humans are artificial by nature (see Philosophical Anthropology). We are deemed to produce our niche since if we do not, we're doomed to die out. That's how bad we're fitted to a supposedly "natural" life. Are you certain it was actual philosophy instead of anthroposophical voodoo?

What the heck??? How in the world could Rousseau, and the Romantic rejection of rationalism, be "off topic" in a philosophy forum?????  This "close everything that a rationalist cabal does not like in philosophy" is out of control!

Yes, there is such an ethical view. But it is as arbitrary as any other. Y'all ought to read Nietzsche. You want guidance, don't look in the Bible; look in the mirror.

@Dcleve Agreed. A large number of people here exist only to pick apart questions and declare that they're not legitimate. I have seen almost no questions on stax that are  illegitimate.

@Miss_Understands One of the references in my answer leads to Nietzsche among others.  Yes, ethics need to be evaluated thru judgement, but no, judgement is not "arbitrary".  I do not look at the Bible, Nietzsche, or the mirror for guidance, but thanks for the suggestions!  :-)

Earth was not "set up" to function as an ecosystem.

If you take the human species as catatgorical then we cannot do anything out of the bounds of a human.

Walking barefoot occasionally where the ground is soft and lacking sharp edges has health advantages. Shoes and soles have protection and speed advantages. It's not the shoe that is unhealthy, but the monotony of never walking without. It's quite stupid to infer the extreme that is good to never wear shoes. And philosophy is not that stupid. It rather detects fallacies.

The philosophic movement you are looking for is Romanticism, in the form in which it was advocated by Rousseau.  https://iep.utm.edu/rousseau/  Rosseau considered humans who lived as part of the biosphere to be wise and healthy, while the strictures of society, plus the artifices of rationality, he considered to lead to unhealthy bodies as well as minds.
Romanticization of nature, and overly optimistic views of the health of living things IN nature, have been an ongoing theme in subsequent romantic, idealist, and environmental writings, over the last several centuries.  Rousseau is far from the last writer who advocated idealization of the natural "order".  Here is a modern cancer paper that asserts that in nature people did not suffer from cancer:  https://www.manchester.ac.uk/about/news/scientists-suggest-that-cancer-is-man-made/  And a rebuttal that says the first paper is wrong:  https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn19591-briefing-cancer-is-not-a-disease-of-the-modern-world/
While the above paragraph criticizes the assumption that humans were cancer-free in the wild, the weaker claim that much of our modern lifestyle increases our cancer risk is epidemiologically supported.  Indoor air pollution from fires for warmth, thru outgassing off fabrics, paints, treated woods, etc. -- most have been found to be carcinogen risks.  The diet we were evolved for is an omnivore diet, with lots of plant products to boost our fiber intake, and little cooked food.  Modern diets, which deliver what we LIKE, more so than what we evolved for, lead to health concerns.  We were also evolved to be far more physically active than a modern lifestyle calls for, and this too causes health concerns.  Psychologically, we developed in communities of no more than 400 individuals.  That we psychologically can operate in a sociological rather than anthropological environment, is actually pretty surprising. That there may be nagging psychological problems we experience in modern societies, is NOT surprising.
Movements and resources that are influenced by environmental romanticism include the Whole Earth Catalog, the Gaia Hypothesis, Prevention magazine, Holism, nudists, and the Deep Ecology ethical movement.
Here are two discussions of where environmentalist and natural order philosophy has gone since Rosseau https://philosophynow.org/issues/106/What_Good_Is_Nature https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/thinking-like-a-mall-environmental-philosophy-after-the-end-of-nature/

They found cancer in kids that were buried in late stone age...what a joke.

@PhilipKlöcking -- The first paper argued that because they didn't find cancer in stone age kids, and childhood bone cancer is one of the more common that affect children today, that no stone age kids got cancer.  The second pointed out that even in our chemical age, childhood bone cancer is only a 1/10,000 rate, so the lack of such cancers in a few child mummies is hardly evidence of a cancer-free era.

@PhilipKlöcking That there are characteristic false beliefs that romanticization of nature can and often does lead one to, seems to have been used to close this question. But ALL philosophic views lead to characteristic errors, as no philosophy successfully closes.  This is a problem with enlightenment rationalism, with materialism, and with physicalism, as well as with their rival philosophies. That a question that has a straightforward philosophy answer: Romanticism, specifically that of Rousseau and various subsequent nature-loving romantics, was called off topic in philosophy is absurd.

The answer could be improved by linking to something describing Rousseau's idea of naturalism, and cutting away the rest. We cannot know if the OP heard about Rousseau or any other new age cult rejecting modernity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism_in_philosophy does not even mention Rousseau

"the weaker claim that much of our modern lifestyle increases our cancer risk is epidemiologically supported." There is no study that shows increased risk of cancer from anything else than humans getting older due to excellent health care. A perfectly modern lifestyle is possible without exposing oneself to significantly heightened carcinogen risks. Finding some change to the environment adds carcinogen risk does not put into question the modern lifestyle as a whole, there are improvements to cancer risk as well to consider. Also https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1091

@tkruse  -- My IEP Rousseau link explicitly cites him as a major influence on Romanic Naturalism, and from the Philosophy Now article about Romanic Naturalism:  "the Romantic movement following on from Rousseau’s ‘back-to-nature’ ethos inspired generations of artists, writers and poets in a positive way".  There are much better references than Wikipedia.  And contrary to your innuendo, your SkepticSE link does not contradict the EPA warning on indoor cancer risks:   https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/volatile-organic-compounds-impact-indoor-air-quality

So weird, I cannot find the EPA recommendation to abandon modern lifetyle and go back to live naked in the woods.

@tkruse  So posting something that is clearly false does not bother you, and rather than correcting the error, you think the better course of action is to distract from, rather than learn from the correction?  "There is no study that shows increased risk of cancer from anything else than humans getting older due to excellent health care. "  The EPA disagrees.

None of what the EPA writes in the link pertains to statistics of mortality rates in humans increasing. Just because there are some know natural and artificial causes of cancer to avoid does not mean humanity as a whole has significantly increased mortality in the statistics. Or to make it more easily understandable for you. Recent studies show that wankink off while driving a car significantly increases risk of accident. But that does not show that there are an increased number of accidents due to wankink. You don't understand maths.

Or otherwise said, modernity makes humans live much longer with much less cancer, even if every now and then we find that some new materials used are carcinogens. But even adding those does not prevent modern medecine from reducing risk of cancer, with old age remaining the most significant factor.


what is most naturally human?

And what is that? Like that's somewhat like giving someone the advice to "just be yourself". The other person knows what that means, but you yourself have no clue of what they consider "quintessentialy you". So for all intents and purposes "humans do what humans naturally do" (and which apparently gets us into messy situations).
So in other words that wouldn't be particularly helpful advice without further context.
Now pre-scientific people speculated a lot about what primitive society would look like, with people like Hobbs essentially arguing that live without civilization is a violent free for all and people should be grateful and embrace the tyrannical overlord that they themselves have created to "civilize" them. While others like Rousseau pondered about the noble savage and how it's really "civilization" that's the corrupting element. Or you know the biblical story of the fall from grace by achieving knowledge or whatnot.
Now with regards to climate change and the apparent unsustainability of our way of life, there is an increased interest in sustainability and/or primitivism so maybe in those backwaters there are also ideas that glorify a more "natural" way of life that gives tribes a lot more credit for sustaining a balanced ecosystem over a way of life that exploits and destroys resources until they are gone for good.
Though that being said it's not that nature is all nice to humans either. Like there are plenty potent nuclear, biological and chemical "weapons" that nature throws quite "organically" at us without our own involvement. Like "the sun is a deadly laser"... Also there's natural cosmic radiation, mountains usually have higher than average radiation, alcohol and nicotine are quite natural as are various other drugs.
Not to mention that, correct me if I'm wrong, cancer isn't so much a "disease" as it is a problem with cell regeneration where a cell, rather than dying just starts to grow. So that's not necessarily something that is new or that we've recently made up and there are plenty of natural carcinogens. That doesn't mean we're not making things worse, but cancer being more of a problem also has something to do with us getting older an other things being less of a problem.
So TL;DR I guess the closest fit is probably sustainability, which is not quite primitivism but aims to strike a natural balance that can be sustained, without endless destruction or suffering.

The sentiment expressed in the question is in philosophy generally categorized as "Romanticism". Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism_in_philosophy
Romanticism generally means putting on rose-tinted glasses about the past and being nostalgic about it. As such it is not a philosophy with assumptions, evidence, formalisms and proofs, but rather a sentiment or a mood that afflicted various writers in philosophy.
Or as the Encyclpedia Britannica puts it:
https://www.britannica.com/art/Romanticism

Romanticism, attitude or intellectual orientation that characterized many works of literature, painting, music, architecture, criticism, and historiography in Western civilization over a period from the late 18th to the mid-19th century.

There is also no consensus on what time in the past was ideal so different writer will write about:

The good old times before the internet
The good old times before the TV
The good old time before the industrialisation
The good old times when parents could physically discipline their children
The good old times when women were not permitted to vote
The good old time before the slavery was abolished
The good old time when parents could force their children into marriage at young age
The good old time before the American revolution
The good old time before the French revolution
The good old time before the white settlers destroyed the americas
The good old times when people were not gay or trans
The good old times when people when greek philosophers could have sex with other men
The good old time before Mohammed
The good old time before Jesus
The good old time before humanity invented writing
The good old time before humanity invented agriculture
The good old time before humanity came into existence

All of those would be examples of Romaticism. As shown from this arbitrary selection, the sentiment is very subjective and does not follow any logic, also is often just factually wrong. Since humanity went through many changes, and each change brought winners and losers, and most periods of change came with friction and suffering, such romantic notions are typically regarded as psychological aversion to change
In philosophy, most attempts to make an argument from that sentimentality are classified as

Fallacy of appeal to nature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_nature



An appeal to nature is a rhetorical technique for presenting and proposing the argument that "a thing is good because it is 'natural', or bad because it is 'unnatural'.




Naturalistic fallacy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy



For the claim that something is good or right because it is natural





Since this is about sentiment, such fallacious arguments are used in commercials (grandmas recipe) and cults (like the Amish, or any that refuse medical treatment) and politics ("Make America great again") for example.
There are fallacies both for the well-being as for ethics.
For well-being, in biology it is known that while the original environment any animal or non-animal species is found in is typically better for that species than arbitrary other environments, the best environment is one that is hand-tailored for that species without all the noise from circumstance, physics and such. And while there are many examples of humans harming the environment while trying to optimize it, those are lessons learned among multitude of successful improvements to the environment.
For ethics, the issue is not only that logically one cannot derive an ought from an is, but also that there cannot be a consensus about what is the historical state that supposedly would allow us to know the perfectly "natural" state.

I don't think the dead romanticist of the 19th century in their graves mind a lot.
